# Can I have a Google Analytics ecommerce transaction without items?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I've searched around to clarify this, I'm pretty sure I can, but just want to make sure.

I want to use Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking to track hotel reservations.  All I'm interested in is the total revenue associated with the transaction.

In the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

It seems to be worded as if you are required to add item objects along with your transaction object.  Am I able to send just a transaction object with no items attached?

Answer (score 1):

The only required elements for the transaction data is a transaction ID, and the only required elements for the transaction products are the transaction ID and the name of the product, as indicated in the same link you posted. Having said that though, if you want to be able to track revenue, you would need to also send price data in the transaction item list.